# Sexual dimorphism of the Amphimachairodus genus of saber-toothed cats

Tags: anatomy, literature, palaeontology, sexual-dimorphism, feline

[*Amphimachairodus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphimachairodus) is an extinct genus of particularly large saber-toothed cats.

Per Alan Turner and Mauricio Antón's *The Big Cats and Their Fossil Relatives: An Illustrated Guide to Their Evolution and Natural History* (which I lack a copy of and cannot find an E-copy of), *Amphimachairodus* was "markedly" [sexually dimorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_dimorphism), "with males being much larger than females".

Before I get into sources, the overall question: **does anyone know how sexually dimorphic *Amphimachairodus* was — specifically in terms of physical size?** Was it like modern lions, where males weigh somewhere between 1½ to 2 times the females, or was it more or less pronounced than that? Google search results for this are few and far between.

Now, I found calculated sexual dimorphism indices for *Machairodus aphanistus* and *Promegantereon ogygia* (not to mention several modern species, such as the lion, serval, leopard, and jaguar, as well as *Smilodon fatalis*) in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24523288?seq=8); said figures suggest *M. aphanistus* was between modern tigers and modern lions in terms of sexual dimorphism. But *Machairodus* is a [wastebasket taxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wastebasket_taxon) out of which several species have been moved into *Amphimachairodus*, so I have no idea whether the figures for *M. aphanistus* are representative of *Amphimachairodus* as a whole.

[This source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235349450_A_Rich_Community_of_Felidae_Mammalia_Carnivora_from_the_Late_Miocene_Turolian_MN_13_Site_of_Las_Casiones_Villalba_Baja_Teruel_Spain) can be cross-checked against the first source to slightly improve one's understanding of *Amphimachairodus*'s overall size over what a Wikipedia article can tell you (specifically, compare tooth sizes), but has no information on sexual dimorphism. The best it gets:

> The three available tali from Las Casiones show strong differences in
> size, but comparable to those observed within the sample from
> Crevillente-2 (Montoya,1994), supporting the existence of strong
> sexual dimorphism in A. giganteus

Indeed, what I assume is mean mesiodistal length ("MDLMean") of the fourth premolar ("P4") of *Amphimachairodus giganteus* varies from 24.9 mm to 32 mm. However, I doubt comparing one type of tooth across a handful of specimens gives an accurate picture of *A. giganteus* size, let alone an accurate picture of dimorphism across all of *Amphimachairodus*. It also means you need to assume that the smallest teeth represent females and the largest ones males, which isn't necessarily true when it comes to big saber-tooths, as *Smilodon* demonstrates.

Basically: I'm asking for information specifically concerning this, if there is any. It would also be helpful to have more sources on the *Amphimachairodus* genus which aren't Wikipedia or books I can't get ahold of without buying them.

I believe Biology Stack Exchange is the best Stack Exchange for posting this question, as Earth Science Stack Exchange's "paleontology" tag states that:

> Questions about the biological aspect of paleontology (such as
> taxonomy and anatomy) are off-topic here and should be asked on
> biology.stackexchange.com